# How to save only one database in Redis?

Tags: redis

I'm new to Redis and I have an issue related to backup.

For now, I have one instance running on a windows server. Inside this instance, I have currently one "job" that stores data in one database. I don't want this data to be backed up.

I have to create a new job. My first idea was to store the data in another database, but on the same instance. Then I would activate RDB backups on this database id.

However, when I read the redis doc, I see this command for backup:

```
save <seconds> <changes>
```

This command just backs up all the database of the current instance.
I don't see any option design to target a specific instance, port or database. Do you know how I can isolate the two jobs, in order to be able to backup only the second ?

My boundary is that I have only one server.

Thank you guys !

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You CANNOT achieve that. With a single Redis instance, you can either save all databases, or save none of them.

In your case, you should create two Redis instances: one of which does no backup, while the other saves its databases to disk. Since you only have one server, you should bind these two instances to different ports.

Redis has very small memory footprint. Two instance DO NOT have performance penalty.

Comment: Thanks for the informations. I do not know how to achieve that on my windows server. I'll do some research, if you know the answer, please share it :)

Comment: By default, Redis binds on port 6379. You can modify redis.conf to change the port: port 6378