# Two rdb files in /var/lib/redis dir

Tags: redis

I wanted to check what `redis` dumps are available so in `redis-cli` I did

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get dir
1) "dir"
2) "/var/lib/redis"
```

also:

```
127.0.0.1:6379> config get databases
1) "databases"
2) "16"
```

In my `/var/lib/redis` dir I discovered 2 `.rdb` files

```
root@docker-elk01:/var/lib/redis# ls -lh
total 4.4G
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis redis 4.4G Feb 22 04:27 dump.rdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 redis redis  28M Feb 22 12:10 temp-66388.rdb
```

What I also noticed is that the `temp-` files comes and goes.

Why are there 2 files?

I know that in our apps we are using 2 dbs as shown below

```
127.0.0.1:6379> info keyspace
# Keyspace
db1:keys=262013,expires=0,avg_ttl=0
db10:keys=199,expires=199,avg_ttl=498984788
```

Does the `dump.rdb` includes a dump from **both** databases?

Can I selectively disable dumps from one of those dbs? (or from both?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Why are there 2 files?

*temp-66388.rdb* is a temp file used to save RDB file. When saving the database to a RDB file, Redis creates a temp file with the process id, and dumps the database to that file. If it dumps the database successfully, Redis rename this temp file to *dump.rdb*. That's why the temp file comes and goes.

> Does the dump.rdb includes a dump from both databases?

YES.

> Can I selectively disable dumps from one of those dbs? (or from both?)

NO, you CANNOT do that. You can either dump all databases, or dump nothing at all. Also check [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44370279/how-to-save-only-one-database-in-redis).

Comment: Why do I have multiple temp .rdb files? @for_stack